# Flex Mobile TextInputSkin for with prompt and Differant Softkeyboards

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, autoresize, soft-keyboard

i am developing Flex mobile application, in which i faces issue related to TextInputSkin, i have applied prompt for all textinput and different Sofykeyboard (number,email,contact etc...).

i grouped the Textinputs in different VGroup and HGroups. i am used the Scroller so when i applied "spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" to TextInput scrolls fine... but when i remove the skin it lags in scrolling...

now the problem with TextInputSkin is it does not take softkeyboards like number,contact,email...
and for prompt value it retains to gray while typing...

do any have solution for this issue ?
and can i apply auto scroll so that when the softkeyboard activates than the view resize appropriately i found resizeForSoftKeyboard property , which resize the view but when softkeyboard deactivates than the view remains same... so you can found the area of softkeyboard "BLACK".

Answer (score 2):

I think the problems you're asking about are just relating to the diferences between the Flex 4.5 textInput skin (which uses the Flash TextField) and the Flex 4.6 skin (which uses StageText).

When not using Stage Text you cannot specify the softKeyboardType

Read more:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextInput.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableStageText.html

To quote some of the limitations of StageText:

> Limitation of StageText-based controls:
>
> ```
> Native text input fields cannot be clipped by other Flex content and are rendered in a layer above the Stage. Because of this
> ```
>
> limitation, components that use StageText-based skin classes will
>   always appear to be on top of other Flex components. Flex popups and
>   drop-downs will also be obscured by any visible native text fields.
>   Finally, native text fields' relative z-order cannot be controlled by
>   the application.
>
> ```
> The native controls do not support embedded fonts.
>
> Links and html markup are not supported.
>
> text is always selectable.
>
> Fractional alpha values are not supported.
>
> Keyboard events are not dispatched for most keys. This means that the tab key will not dispatch keyDown or keyUp events so focus cannot
> ```
>
> be removed from a StageText-based control with the tab key.
>
> ```
> StageText is currently not capable of measuring text.
>
> At this time StageText does not support programmatic control of scroll position.
>
> At this time StageText does not support an event model necessary to allow for touch-based scrolling of forms containing native text fields.
> ```